# Getting running services (LINUX JAVA): how to parse service name only?

Tags: java, linux, parsing, service

I am trying to get the running services of a linux machine.  I have printed them but I want to get the service name only.  My code:

```
   public void runningservices()
{

    try {
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -e");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.

        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am getting the result in this format:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:46 init
    2 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
    3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
    4 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
    5 ?        00:00:00 events/0
    6 ?        00:00:00 khelper
    7 ?        00:00:00 kthread
    9 ?        00:00:00 xenwatch
   10 ?        00:00:00 xenbus
   12 ?        00:00:05 kblockd/0
   13 ?        00:00:00 kacpid
  176 ?        00:00:00 cqueue/0
  180 ?        00:00:00 khubd
  182 ?        00:00:00 kseriod
  246 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
  247 ?        00:00:00 pdflush
  248 ?        00:00:01 pdflush
  249 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
  250 ?        00:00:00 aio/0
  457 ?        00:00:00 kpsmoused
  485 ?        00:00:00 mpt_poll_0
  486 ?        00:00:00 mpt/0
  487 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
  490 ?        00:00:00 ata/0
  491 ?        00:00:00 ata_aux
  496 ?        00:00:00 kstriped
  505 ?        00:00:00 ksnapd
  516 ?        00:00:12 kjournald
  547 ?        00:00:00 kauditd
  580 ?        00:00:03 udevd
 1865 ?        00:00:00 kmpathd/0
 1866 ?        00:00:00 kmpath_handlerd
 1925 ?        00:00:00 kjournald
```

But I want it like this:

```
init
migration
ksoftirqd
watchdog
events
khelper
kthread
xenwatch
xenbus
kblockd
kacpid
cqueue
khubd
kseriod
khungtaskd
pdflush
pdflush
kswapd0
aio
kpsmoused
mpt_poll_0
mpt
scsi_eh_0
ata
ata_aux
kstriped
ksnapd
kjournald
kauditd
udevd
kmpathd
kmpath_handlerd
kjournald
```

How would I parse it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the length of the string **line** and get the characters backward from **IndexOf(length-1)** upto the first space.

Answer (score 2):

Instead parsing the output, I would look `ps` arguments with `man ps`.

From there you can see a section for user defined outputs;

```
To see every process with a user-defined format:
          ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm
          ps axo stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,pgrp,ppid,pid,pcpu,comm
          ps -eopid,tt,user,fname,tmout,f,wchan
```

For your situation, running this would be the answer;

```
ps -eo comm
```

Answer (score 1):

Java style :

```
 while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] split = line.split(" ");
        System.out.println(split[split.length-1]);

}
```

Comment: thanks it works for me can you tell me the logic that you have done in this code ?

Comment: Split/separate line string with a space and store each of split string data into array. You want the data on the last of string, that would be inside the last index of array, which we can get by split.length-1 (note that array index start with 0, so we need to minus by 1)

Answer (score 0):

change your command to

```
ps -e | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: it is giving me many process i think almost all either they are running or not?? while the command i am using giving me running services

Comment: It gives you exactly what you expect, without changing your Java code. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: i tried it but it give me extra process too that i am not getting from my previous command

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that this disturbs you.

Comment: mate its fine i have goy soulution from *Snoke